# What is this bizarre tkinter error in my timer?

Tags: python, tkinter

I decided to make a `tkinter` timer but am receiving a very strange error.
Here is the code and the error:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Hello wold")
window.geometry("300x300")
timer = int(input("time in seconds"))

for i in range(timer):
  timer -= 1
  print(timer)
  time.sleep(1)
  hello = tk.Label("timer")
  hello.pack()
  tk.mainloop()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    hello = tk.Label("timer")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3143, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2561, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2530, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Comment: The first parameter to any Tkinter widget is the parent window, Frame, or other container - probably `window` in your case.  The text of a Label has to be specified via a `text=` keyword parameter.

Comment: @jasonharper like: hello = tk.Label(text = str(timer))

Comment: @coderboi: No, like: `hello = tk.Label(window, text=str(timer))`. See [documentation](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/label.html).

Answer (score 0):

To change the text of a label you need to define the text property:

```
hello = tk.Label(text="timer")
```

This will set the text of the label to "timer", but if you want to set it as the variable you previously declared (called timer) - simply remove the quotation marks.

```
hello = tk.Label(text=timer)
```

This will set the text of the label to whatever the variable 'timer' is equal to.
However you also need to set the window, which leaves the final code to this:

```
hello = tk.Label(window, text=timer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: change `tk.mainloop()` to `window.mainloop()`.

- I added `tk.StringVar` in line 16.
- I added `textvariable=string_variable` in line 17
- tk.mainloop was relocated outside of the loop block in line 20 and renamed to `window.mainloop()`

Here is code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Hello wold") 
window.geometry("300x300")
 

timer = int(input("time in seconds"))

for i in range(timer):
  timer -= 1
  print(timer)
  time.sleep(1)

  string_variable = tk.StringVar(window, timer)   
  hello = tk.Label(window, textvariable=string_variable)
  hello.pack()
 
window.mainloop()
```

Output result:

[image]